# change mysql data output with a cursor

Tags: mysql, cursor

I have a challenging data output with the following:

```
**AD_ID         Keyword**
6005090341554   Vitamin C
6005090341554   Vitaminsiz
6005090341554   Supplement Superstores
6005090341554   #Dietary supplement
```

My questions is how do I make my query output the following way:

```
**Ad_ID         Keywords**
6005090341554   Vitamin C,Vitaminsiz,Supplement Superstores,#Dietary supplement
```

thank you!

Comment: Can you show the query you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT Ad_ID,GROUP_CONCAT(Keyword) as Keywords FROM my_table GROUP by Ad_ID;
```